# trim results from invoke-restmehod

Tags: rest, powershell, trim

I'm running a Invoke-RestMethod to an api and do a select-object for the result.

$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Get
$result|Select-Object ID,User,Descripton

result is like this:

```
ID User Description                                                  
-- ---- -----------
1 1234  HP EliteBook 840 G3 - 14” - Core i7 6500U - 8 GB RAM - 256 GB SSD
2 3251  HP EliteBook 840 G3 - 14” - Core i7 6500U - 8 GB RAM - 256 GB SSD
3 4323  HP EliteBook 840 G3 - 14” - Core i7 6500U - 8 GB RAM - 256 GB SSD
```

is there a way to trim the Description value on the fly so it only says the model? like this

```
ID User Description                                                  
-- ---- -----------
1 1234  HP EliteBook 840 G3
2 3251  HP EliteBook 840 G3
3 4323  HP EliteBook 840 G3
```

Comment: Yes, google "calculated properties" which you can do in your select statement, you'd also obviously need to figure out the right way to do the trim. Can't advise more directly as am out ATM, hence comment not answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could split on `-` then take the first entry in the array. As Mark pointed out you should put this in a calculated property.

```
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Get $result | 
    Select-Object ID,User,@{name="Descripton";Expression=($_.Description.split('-')[0]).trim()}
```

Comment: thanks will look into this further, right now I get "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

Comment: Think the 14" is a problem.
this works:
$test='HP EliteBook 840 G3 - 14” - Core i7 6500U - 8 GB RAM - 256 GB SSD'
$test.Split("-")[0].Trim()

Comment: $result|Select-Object ID,User,@{name='Model';Expression=("Description").Split("-")[0].Trim()} still gives the whole description.

Comment: got it to work: $result|Select-Object AssetNo,EquipmentID,UserID,@{n='Model';e={ $_.Description.split('-')[0].trim() }}